# Can you please correct this bash

Tags: linux, bash

I was able to manage listing all mail account like:

```
for dir in /home/*/mail/*/*; do
    echo "$dir"  | awk -F"/" '{print $6"@"$5}' done

Results:
user@domain.com
user2@domain2.com
etc...
```

But I can not get this work like:

```
for dir in /home/*/mail/*/*; do
    doveadm expunge -u "$dir" mailbox '*' savedbefore 100days   | awk -F"/" '{print $6"@"$5}'
done
```

Working command is:

```
doveadm expunge -u user@domain.com mailbox '*' savedbefore 100days
```

I have no idea about bash but I feel like it is easy to correct syntax. So can you please correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
for dir in /home/*/mail/*/*; do
  dir=$(echo "$dir" | awk -F"/" '{print $6"@"$5}')
  doveadm expunge -u "$dir" mailbox '*' savedbefore 100days
done
```

Comment: The problem is that OP uses the absolute pathname starting with `/` as the argument of the `-u` option. The answer ensures that the argument is an email address.

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is this suitable for sh cronjobs? Should I remove print part?